# Why Does Subsets[...,{n}] not Output a Packed List, Even Though it Doesn't Unpack?

Tags: core-language, combinatorics, implementation-details, language-design, packed-arrays

Assume `list` is packed.

I expect `Subsets[]` is a structural operation because it depends on the number of elements, not on what the elements are. The output for `Subsets[list]` is ragged, and this is why it will not be packed. However, `Subsets[list,{n}]` does not have this problem. It seems to be a structural operation whose output is rectangular. Why is the output not packed? Moreover, `Subsets[list,{n}]` does not unpack (which can be determined using `On["Packing"]`).

The same can be asked about the related function `Subsequences[list,{n}]` whose output is not packed, and the output of `IntegerPartitions[m,{n}]` ($m>n$) is not packed as well.

```
Subsets[Range[10], {3}] // PackedArrayQ
Subsequences[Range[10], {3}] // PackedArrayQ
IntegerPartitions[10, {3}] // PackedArrayQ

(*False*)
(*False*)
(*False*)
```

On the other hand, the related functions `Tuples[list,n]` and `Permutations[list,n]` have packed outputs.

Moreover, it seems like there are many ways to make a program that does what `Subsets[list,{n}]` but with an output that is packed (nested loops, `Map[]`, `Table[]`, removing elements from `Tuples[list,n]` or from `Permutations[list,{n}]` all come to mind).

Comment: Just to clarify, I see two issues: Why is `list` unpacked? and, Why is the output not packed? The focus of the question seems to be on the second (that is, on the output). To my mind "to unpack" means to transform from packed to not packed and is an expensive operation. Unpacking does not happen in these three cases, so I take the question to be, Why is the output not generated as a packed array?

Comment: If `f[list]` is computed as `Join @@ Table[f[list, {n}], {n, 0, Length@list}]`, then you wouldn't want them packed, since you would waste time unpacking them when joined. One might write a separate function for the special case with a different core routine, as you say, but perhaps they didn't want to. The internal workings and reasonings are probably only known (and perhaps now forgotten) by WRI developers.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Regarding your comment "Unpacking does not happen in these three cases...", perhaps I misunderstand you, but how is it possible for the input (`list`) to be packed, the output be not packed, and yet the input list is not unpacked by the operation?

Comment: `list` is unpacked (at least by one of the commands, I forget which). Use `On["Packing"]` and execute your examples to see.  As to how the input can be packed and the output not, try `list = Range@5; Table[list[[k ;; k + 2]], {k, 1, 
   Length@list - 2}] // Developer`PackedArrayQ` (with the `"Packing"` messages on.).  Then try it with `list = Range@500`.  The output being packed or not has nothing to do with `list` be unpacked or not.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you Michael. When I asked "how is it possible", I was looking for a lower-level explanation. If I think of "the operation" as everything that happens between the input and output, it seems it is a logical consequence, not a programmatic one, that "the operation" must unpack if the input is packed and the output is not. However, my question may be a restatement of your "Why is the output not generated as a packed array?". A related question is "How can the input be packed, the output be unpacked, and `On["Packing"]` not mention some sort of unpacking?"

Comment: We're thinking of "unpacking" in two senses. There is a technical sense of "unpacking" used on this site and in the ``Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack`` message. It refers to transforming a packed array to the same array, but unpacked. The operation involves copying the data from a C-style array, to a `List` structure with pointers to expressions representing each number in the array. It seems that the question is, "Why is the output not packed?" My response, not an answer, was, "The internal workings and reasonings are probably only known (and perhaps now forgotten) by WRI developers."

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but there is a workaround.

```
ClearAll[subsets];
subsets[n_Integer, k_Integer] :=
  Module[{res = GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[Range[n - k + 1], k]},
   Statistics`Library`MatrixRowTranslate[res, Range[0, k - 1]];
   res
   ];

subsets[A_List, k_Integer] := Partition[A[[Flatten@subsets[Length@A, k]]], k];
```

Test cases

`subsets[5, 2]`

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {3,
> 5}, {4, 5}}

`` Developer`PackedArrayQ[%] ``

> True

`subsets[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}, 3]`

> {{a,b,c},{a,b,d},{a,b,e},{a,c,d},{a,c,e},{a,d,e},{b,c,d},{b,c,e},{b,d,e},{c,d,e}}

```
r1 = subsets[26, 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
r2 = subsets[Range[26], 10]; // AbsoluteTiming
r3 = Subsets[Range[26], {10}]; // AbsoluteTiming
SameQ[r1, r2, r3]
```

> {0.132365, Null}
> {0.592547, Null}
> {0.862341, Null}
> True

You can also use `` GroupTheory`Tools`MultiSubsets ``, but it's not very efficient.

See also
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/268721/2090