# Fastest way to generate {{a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,b},{b,c},{c,c}} from {a,b,c}

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

What is the fastest way to generate `{{a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,b},{b,c},{c,c}}` from `l={a,b,c}`? I've tried

`Flatten[Table[{l[[i]],l[[j]]},{i,Length@l},{j,i,Length@l}],1]`

but is there a faster and perhaps more elegant way (maybe with `Tuples`)?

Comment: `l // ({#, #} & /* Tuples /* DeleteDuplicatesBy[Intersection])` should work.

Comment: This is about 2.5 times as slow as my original attempt with `Flatten`.

Comment: `ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][l, 2, OrderedQ]` slow but elegant.

Comment: there is the "hey, that's not what I meant!" way: `{{a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,b},{b,c},{c,c}}&[l]`. seems *blazingly* fast. ;)

Comment: Just wondering:  what does speed have to do with such a trivial and blindingly fast calculation?  Why would anyone care?

Comment: It's a minimal example with three elements. Actually, I do such calculations/generations with about 10^5 elements.

Comment: @thorimur: Joker! :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets[{a, b, c}, 2]
```

> {{a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,b},{b,c},{c,c}}

Comment: So far the fastest method for my purposes and also very elegant!

Answer (score 21):

```
Select[Tuples[{a,b,c},2],OrderedQ]
```

Comment: This is about twice as fast as my original attempt with `Flatten`, wonderful!

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility is to use [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
Pick[
    Tuples[{a,b,c}, 2],
    Flatten @ UpperTriangularize @ ConstantArray[1, {3, 3}],
    1
]
```

> {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}}

Answer (score 10):

Using an inverse [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function):

```
SetAttributes[toPair, Listable];
toPair[r_Integer?Positive] := With[{c = Quotient[NumberTheory`IntegerSqrt[8 r] + 1, 2]},
                                    {Quotient[c (3 - c), 2] + r - c, c}]
```

we can do the following:

```
list = {a, b, c};
list[[#]] & /@ SortBy[toPair[Range[Binomial[Length[list] + 1, 2]]], First]
   {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}}
```

Answer (score 9):

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235768/72111

```
m = 3;
n = 2;
list = Subsets[Range[2, m + n], {n}];
result = Subtract[#, Range[n]] & /@ list
Alphabet[][[1 ;; m]][[#]] & /@ result
```

- Test the timming.

```
(m = 26;
  n = 6;
  list = Subsets[Range[2, m + n], {n}];
  result = Subtract[#, Range[n]] & /@ list;
  Alphabet[][[1 ;; m]][[#]] & /@ result) // AbsoluteTiming
```

- compare with

```
Select[Tuples[Alphabet[], 6], OrderedQ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: This is about 26 times as slow as my original attempt with `Flatten`.

Comment: @Thrash Please compare with `Select[Tuples[Range[26], 5], OrderedQ] // AbsoluteTiming` and `(m = 26;
  n = 5;
  list = Subsets[Range[2, m + n], {n}];
  result = Subtract[#, Range[n]] & /@ list) // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: I think your code is very fast for large `n`, but for my current purposes I need only the case `n=2`. Compare `Select[Tuples[Alphabet[], 2], OrderedQ]; // RepeatedTiming` with `(m = 26;  n = 2; list = Subsets[Range[2, m + n], {n}];   result = Subtract[#, Range[n]] & /@ list;  Alphabet[][[1 ;; m]][[#]] & /@ result;) // RepeatedTiming`. On my computer about 67 times as slow as the `Select` method. Thanks anyway, it could be useful one day!

Answer (score 8):

**(a) Subsets and Transpose**

```
{Subsets[#,{2}],Transpose[{#,#}]}&@{a,b,c}//Catenate//Sort

(* {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}} *) 

{Subsets[#,{2}],Transpose[{#,#}]}&@{a,b,c,d}//Catenate//Sort

(* {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, c}, {c, d}, {d, d}} *)
```

**(b) Complement, Tuples and Subsets**

```
Complement[Tuples[{a,b,c},2],Subsets[Reverse@{a,b,c},{2}]]

(* {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}} *)

Complement[Tuples[{a,b,c,d},2],Subsets[Reverse@{a,b,c,d},{2}]]

(* {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, c}, {c, d}, {d, d}} *)

// Complement conveniently sorts
```

**(c) Distribute**

```
Distribute[{l,l}, List,List, Select[{##},OrderedQ]&]

(* {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}} *)
```

#### Just for fun

##### Subsets and Transpose

```
subsets=Thread[Subsets[Range[20],{2}] -> 1];
transpose=Thread[Transpose[{Range[20],Range[20]}] -> 2];

ArrayPlot[SparseArray@Join[subsets,transpose], 
  Mesh-> True,
  ColorRules -> {1 -> Purple, 2 -> Green},
  ImageSize->200]
```

[image: Array Plot of Tuples and Transpose]

##### Tuples/Distribute

```
ArrayPlot[SparseArray@Thread[Tuples[Range[20],{2}]->1], 
  Mesh->True, 
  ColorRules -> {1 -> Blue},
  ImageSize->200]
```

[image: ArrayPlot of Tuples]

##### `Subsets[list]` and `Subsets[Reverse@list]`

```
subsets=Thread[Subsets[Range[20],{2}] -> 1];
subsetsReversed=Thread[Subsets[Reverse@Range[20],{2}] -> 2];

ArrayPlot[SparseArray@Join[subsets,subsetsReversed], Mesh-> True,ColorRules -> {1 -> Purple, 2 -> Violet },ImageSize->200]
```

[image: Subsets and reversed subset plots]

Answer (score 8):

Using `Cases`:

```
Cases[Tuples[{a, b, c}, 2], _?OrderedQ] // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.0000291, {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}}}*)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Outer[List, {a,b,c},{a,b,c}] //
Flatten[#,1]& //
Select[OrderedQ]
```

> {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}}

Answer (score 8):

If the performance is important, try this

```
ClearAll[combinationsWithReplacement];

combinationsWithReplacement[A_?VectorQ, k_Integer] :=
  With[{m = Length@A + k - 1},
   Partition[Part[A, Flatten@(Developer`ToPackedArray@Subsets[Range@m, {k}] +
        ConstantArray[-Range[0, k - 1], Binomial[m, k]])], k]
   ];

combinationsWithReplacement[{a, b, c}, 2]
combinationsWithReplacement[Range[26], 7] // Dimensions // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {{a, a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {b, b}, {b, c}, {c, c}}
> {0.833452, {3365856, 7}}

Answer (score 7):

```
n = 2000;
alphabet = Range[n];(*or whatever you like*)
result = Transpose[{
   Join @@ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#1, n + 1 - #2] &, alphabet],
   Join @@ Map[alphabet[[# ;;]] &, Range[n]]
   }];
```

Seems to be about twice as fast as Carl Woll's `Pick` method (which I really like!).

Answer (score 3):

A rip off from python's itertools:

```
ClearAll[combinations$with$replacement] ;
combinations$with$replacement[sequence_, r_] := Block[
    {n, indices, result, range, flag, i, j},
    n = Length[sequence] ;
    indices = ConstantArray[1, r] ;
    result = {sequence[[indices]]} ;
    range = Reverse[Range[r]] ;
    While[
        True,
        Do[
            j = i ;
            flag = True ;
            If[
                indices[[i]] != n,
                flag = False ;
                Break[] ;
            ],
            {i, range}
        ] ;
        If[flag, Return[result]] ;
        indices[[j;;]] = ConstantArray[indices[[j]] + 1, r - j + 1] ;
        result = Join[result, {sequence[[indices]]}]
    ] ;
] ;
combinations$with$replacement[{a, b, c}, 2]
(* {{a,a},{a,b},{a,c},{b,b},{b,c},{c,c}} *)
```